# VS Code - Get and Use Current Icon Set

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension for VS Code and have been asked to dynamically use the current icon set's icons inside of a TreeView.

Reading through the VS Code Variable References - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

I didn't see anything about accessing the icon set other than in the User and Workspaces docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations

Is there a means of determining the current set via the User Settings programmatically?

My thought would be to grab the name of the icon set, then just search through my `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions` folder and extract the icon files that I need.

So where are the User level settings for the `"workbench.iconTheme"` stored in order to read the value?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in the settings JSON you could read the value of `workbench.iconTheme` and do further processing from there.